# Dequeue function does not work

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to learn about C using codeblock, part of my assignment is to use queue as an input and output method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct QUEUE {
    int head, tail;
    int list[4];
} queue;

void create( queue *q ) {
    q->head = 0;
    q->tail = 0;
}

int empty( queue *q ) {
    if ( q->tail == 0 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int full( queue *q ) {
    if ( q->tail == 4 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void enqueue( queue *q ) {
    int i, data;
    if ( full( q ) == 1 )
        printf( "\nQueue is Full" );
    else {
        printf( "\nEnqueue Integer : " );
        scanf( "%d", &data );
        q->list[q->tail] = data;
        q->tail++;
    }
}

void dequeue( queue *q ) {
    int i;
    if ( empty( q ) == 1 )
        printf( "\n Queue is Empty" );
    else
        q->head++;
}

void main( ) {
    int select;
    queue q;

    create( &q );

    while ( 1 ) {
        printf( "\n1->Enqueue \t 2->Dequeue \t 3->Exit: " );
        scanf( "%d", &select );

        switch ( select ) {
        case 1:     enqueue( &q );
                    break;
        case 2:     dequeue( &q );
                    break;
        default:    goto out;
        }
    }
out:
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Thats my code, the dequeue function returns queue is empty at first, but after I enqueue an integer, it wont dequeue at all. Thanks for your help. I'm using codeblock to compile my program.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to have with `dequeue`? Perhaps to reset it back to its original state?

Comment: Yes, but the dequeue function wont work if the queue is full or not.

Comment: Are you saying that once you `enqueue` a single value, using `dequeue` twice doesn't print "Queue is empty"?

Comment: voting to close. you haven't told what your code supposed to do, so we cannot help fixing it.

Comment: Neither the tail or the head members are being used correctly in this code. It is missing the necessary code to manage the *difference* between the head and tail to determine full, empty, and number-of-elements info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new variable size inside the struct QUEUE, which is initialized to 0 when the queue is created and refers to the amount of data stored in you queue.

```
typedef struct QUEUE {
    int head, tail,size;
    int list[4];
} queue;

void create( queue *q ) {
    q->head = 0;
    q->tail = -1;
    q->size=0;
}
```

Hence size 0 would mean no data is present in our queue and size 4 will mean the queue is full.

```
int empty( queue *q ) {
    if ( q->size==0 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int full( queue *q ) {
    if ( q->size==4)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

When you enqueue a data, size is increased by 1 and when you dequeue a data, size is decreased by 1.

```
void enqueue( queue *q ) {
    int i, data;
    if ( full( q ) == 1 )
        printf( "\nQueue is Full" );
    else {
        printf( "\nEnqueue Integer : " );
        scanf( "%d", &data );
        q->tail++;
        q->size++;
        if(q->tail==4){
            q->tail=0;
        }
        q->list[q->tail] = data;
        if(tail==4){
            q->tail==0;
        }
    }
}

void dequeue( queue *q ) {
    int i;
    if ( empty( q ) == 1 )
        printf( "\n Queue is Empty" );
    else{
        q->head++;
        q->size--;
    }
}
```

NOTE-Your code lacked the circular flow of queue. When tail has crossed the last block of memory allocated, it should get to the first block.

So, we added this inside the enqueue function:

```
if(tail==4){
                q->tail==0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as per your comment, you seem to want to have your `queue` get reset when you pass its address into the `dequeue` function. This will be a kind of a superficial answer, but why don't you just reset the `q->tail` back to `0` inside the `dequeue` function whenever necessary?

```
void dequeue( queue *q ) {
    int i;
    if ( ... )
        printf( ... );
    else
        q->tail = 0;    // <-- changed this
}
```

The `head` property inside the structure seems to have no use at all, at least for now.

Comment: thanks, but that resets the whole queue, what im going for is for the node to be deleted one at a time.

Comment: @user3483503 There are no such things as *nodes* in your code... Do you, perhaps, want `dequeue` to get rid of only the first element queued in?

Answer (score 0):

A queue is a FIFO (First In, First Out), and you have a fixed sized FIFO (4 integers) along with a "pointer" to the head and tail.

Looking at your code, `tail` points to the next available space, while `head` points to the first filled space.

When you `enqueue` you add the value and increment the value in `tail`.

When you `dequeue` you increment the value in `head`.

This is okay, except that `head` and `tail` are supposed to be indices of an array. At no point to you decrement the values stored inside them. This means that once you have added 4 values to the queue, you can never add any more.

You also assume that the list is empty when `tail == 0`, but what if `head == tail` and `head == 1`, according to your code, the list is empty in this case, but the `empty` function won't know that it's empty.

Since you are not using dynamic memory, I would remove the `head` variable altogether.

When you `dequeue`, I would move the values in the internal array into the previous index. So `list[1]` gets put into `list[0]`. And then decrement `tail`.